# Cshtml Unable to Resolve Reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm adding Microsoft.Web.Optimization to an MVC 4 Beta project.

My _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Microsoft.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/Framework/js", true)"></script>
```

complains

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

However, any .cs file in the project can resolve that type (for example, a controller).

Do I need to do something to inform a .cshtml page about the newly added reference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out NuGet offered me and old version, 0.1.  I'm not sure why that caused this issue, but removing that reference and adding 1.0.0-Pre through NuGet resolved the issue

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Optimization

Note that the namespace has changed to `System.Web.Optimization` in this release.

Comment: Use "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" instead

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error all of a sudden, the usual trick of restarting IIS didn't work, but restarting Visual Studio did.